# Activity Intent SerializableExtra became null, any ideas?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

First of all this crash reproduced **once** on **user** device, so it's not misspelling or another ease to find mistake.
So my code looks something like this:

```
class TradingPositionDetailsActivity : BaseToolbarActivity() {
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
    tradingPositions =
        intent.getSerializableExtra(TRADING_POSITIONS) as List<TradingPosition>
    ...
}

...

companion object {

    private const val SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_position"
    private const val TRADING_POSITIONS = "trading_positions"

    fun startActivity(
        activity: Activity,
        data: List<TradingPosition>,
        tradingPosition: TradingPosition
    ) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, TradingPositionDetailsActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(SELECTED_POSITION, tradingPosition)
        intent.putExtra(TRADING_POSITIONS, data as Serializable)

        val activityOptionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity)
        activity.startActivity(intent, activityOptionsCompat.toBundle())
    }
}
```

}

So **Kotlin ensures we pass non-null value** at startActivity method, but when I try to get extra from intent it throw

```
Caused by kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.List<com.myapp.business.models.TradingPosition>
   at com.myapp.activities.TradingPositionDetailsActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:98)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `List<TradingPosition>`? Is this an `ArrayList` or something else? Android already knows how to deal with certain types when you add them as "extras". It is likely that the method `getSerializableExtra()` returns `null` because the `List` is being added as an "extra" with a different type than the one you expect.

Comment: Is `TradingPositionDetailsActivity` marked as `exported="true"` in the manifest? If so, it's possible that the `Activity` was launched by some other process, without providing the required `Intent` extras as you do in your code.

Comment: @David Wasser The list come from 3 places and it's always `ArrayList`, and i think if the list wouldn't be `Serializable` I get exception in `startActivity`, isn't it? 
@kcoppock There is no such thing as `exported='true` and i think the default is `false`.

Comment: You should add debug logging. Before you call `startActivity()`, examine all the extras in the `Intent` and log them. Do the same in `onCreate()` of the target `Activity`. Post the results in your question.

Comment: @DavidWasser But how it can help? If there was nulls before startActivity() it would crash because it's Kotlin

Comment: No, you don't understand. I assume that you are not adding a `null` "extra" to the `Intent`. The problem is that you are calling `getSerializableExtra()` on the `Intent`. If the extra you are looking for is not there, or it was not stored as a `Serializable`, or the deserialization fails, this method will return `null`. And that is probably what is happening.

Comment: For example, if you call `putBooleanExtra("foo", true) and then call `getSerializableExtra("foo")` this will return `null` because the extra was not stored as a `Serializable`, it was stored as a `Boolean`.

Comment: @DavidWasser I don't understand your example because i will always call `Intent putExtra(String name, Serializable value) `, so the only thing i can imagine is object wasn't serialized while activity cleared by Android and after restoration it have null, but i thought Android somehow guarantee this won't happen.

Comment: Did you add the debug logging like I suggested?

Comment: Not yet, this problem occurred on user's device and we didn't upload new release to google play